# Convert seconds to days, hours, etc on axis labels

Tags: python, streamlit, altair

I am trying to plot a chart which needs to have duration times in terms of "days, hours, minutes" on the Y axis and just dates on the X axis. I can do this easily if the duration is expressed in seconds but in order to improve readability I'd like to change the Y labels to be something like `DTHH:MM`, e.g., `1 Day(s) 10:23`. Does anyone know how can this be accomplished?

This is my current code snippet:

```py
chart = (
        alt.Chart(aggregated_df, title=metric_name_to_display)
        .mark_line(point=True)
        .encode(
            alt.X(f"yearmonthdatehours({QUERY_TIME_COLUMN_NAME}):O").title("Date"),
            alt.Y(f"{metric_name}:Q").title(metric_name_to_display),
            alt.Color("Index:N"),  # type: ignore
            alt.Tooltip(
                [metric_name, f"yearmonthdatehours({QUERY_TIME_COLUMN_NAME}):O"]
            ),
        )
    )
```

where `aggregated_df` is of the form

```py
query_time                        recovered_seconds_all_ingest 
        
0  2024-01-01 00:00:00+00:00       827183
1  2024-01-01 12:00:00+00:00       1832
2  2024-01-02 00:00:00+00:00       829301
3  2024-01-02 12:00:00+00:00       29191
```